# Maven 2.2.1 repository order seems arbitrary

Tags: java, maven

My build is breaking on a fresh machine because one of the repositories is returning a 301 page for both the pom and jar instead of the expected 404. The dependency is asm:asm:1.3. It is in Central, but Maven doesn't seem to be looking there.

Here's a sample of the build log:

```
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'asm:asm:pom:3.1' in repository java.net2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2)
Downloading: http://repository.primefaces.org/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'asm:asm:pom:3.1' in repository prime-repo (http://repository.primefaces.org)
Downloading: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss//asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'asm:asm:pom:3.1' in repository jboss-public-repository-group (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/)
Downloading: http://maven.thebuzzmedia.com/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'asm:asm:pom:3.1' in repository The Buzz Media Maven Repository (http://maven.thebuzzmedia.com)
Downloading: http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.pom
185b downloaded  (asm-3.1.pom)
[WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '6c9fd3d150b8a5f0ca676f49b8ed603793cabebb'; remote = '<html>
<head><title>301' - RETRYING
Downloading: http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.pom
185b downloaded  (asm-3.1.pom)
[WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '6c9fd3d150b8a5f0ca676f49b8ed603793cabebb'; remote = '<html>
<head><title>301' - IGNORING
[WARNING] POM for 'asm:asm:pom:3.1:compile' is invalid.
```

Here's the repositories section in my pom.xml:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>java.net2</id>
        <name>Repository hosting the jee6 artifacts</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>Prime Technology Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
        <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>The Buzz Media Maven Repository</id>
        <url>http://maven.thebuzzmedia.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I don't have a settings.xml file.

From what I can tell, the dependency on jersey-server-1.3 is breaking the build. Its pom.xml specifies the now non-existant repository at `http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish`. But all the other repositories I have specified are being checked in the order I have specified. That is, everything except central. How can I make Maven check the central repository first? Or at least make it check Central before using repositories specified in dependencies' poms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first recommendation i can make is to read the [sonatype article about repositories in your pom](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/). Furthermore the [http code 301 means in move permanently](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). This means your URL you are using for one of your repositories seemed to be out of date or should be different. 
The defined [glassfish repository seemed to wrong](https://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/public/), cause it should be an https connection.

Furthmore i can recommend to [use a repository manager](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html).

One questions comes to my mind: Why are you defining Maven Central in your repositories list, cause it's already defined in Maven itself...BTW: Repository definition should be put into the settings.xml instead of the pom.xml apart from using a repository manager.

To define the order of the repository access it is done in [reverse order based on their definition in the settings.xml](https://community.jboss.org/message/576851). To get better control over this is to use a repository manager.

One important question: Why don't you use Maven 3.0.X instead of Maven 2.2.1 ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the resources to build infrastructure just to compile Java programs, so a repository manager is out of the question. According to the sonatype article, in my situation it is more suitable to put the repositories in the pom. I sometimes collaborate with others so the project has to be portable - not dependent on user-specific configuration. I defined the central repo explicitly because it was not being considered. It still isn't, so I posted this question. I'm not using Maven 3 because it won't build my project. Perhaps I need to investigate Maven 3 further.

Comment: Just got a Mac and built the project with NetBeans' embedded Maven, which is 3.0.x. I didn't have to change anything at all. Nothing else had yet been built via Maven on this machine, so it was a clean environment from the start. So it looks promising. Next time I try a Centos deployment - which involves building from source - I'll have a stab at using 3.0.x. If that builds, I'll mark your answer as resolved for suggesting Maven 3.0.x.

Comment: Accepting on the basis of Maven 3.x suggestion only. Setting up infrastructure for small teams (like me team of one) seems like overkill.

Comment: Not really. I'm working at home only alone but i have installed a repo manager which save a lot of work.